# Python utility to print graph to scale?

Tags: python, printing, graph, scale

Are there any python utilities that will plot a matplotlib or similar graphical output to scale. I'm an mech engineer, and this would be a great utility to have!

If one doesn't exist, what considerations would be need to make such a utility regarding printing and scale?